# Разница между bindActionCreators и dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flux

Захотелось получить ответ на вопрос, который мучает:) В интернете не нашел хорошего ответа (может плохо искал).

Имеется несколько компонент.

В одних делаю:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch)
    }
}
```

Где ActionCreators это объект с экспортируемыми функциями. После оборачиваю mapDispatchToProps и mapStateToProps в connect:

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

Далее вызываю эти функции:

```
this.props.actions.myFunc()
```

В других компонентах делаю без mapDispatchToProps, просто:

```
connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
```

Импортирую все экшены отдельно:

```
import { myFunc, action, another_action } from '../actions'
```

И вызываю функции:

```
this.props.dispatch(myFunc())
```

Никогда не задумывался есть ли между этими подходами разница, поэтому использовал тот способ, который считал удобнее.

Вопрос такой: есть ли какая принципиальная разница (например в плане производительности), между двумя этими подходами, или же это одно и то же действие которое описано двумя разными способами?

Comment: эмм, а из названий разве не понятно?)

Comment: @xFloooo нет, было бы здорово если бы вы прокомментировали.

Comment: @xFloooo то что они делают я понимаю, мне интересна именно принципиальная разница между этими подходами.

Comment: вам уже написали ответ, объяснение очень простое - это всего лишь "сахар"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Принципиальной разницы нет:
`bindActionCreators` оборачивает каждый экшн в `dispatch`, поэтому когда мы вызываем `this.props.actions.myFunc()` происходит dispatch экшена myFunc, только он скрыт под капотом.

Answer (score 2):

Это такой же сахар как и **combineReducers**:

```
const rootReducer = (state = {}, action) => ({
   node1: node1Reducer(state.node1, action),
   node2: node2Reducer(state.node2, action)
   ...
});
```

Что эквивалентно:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    node1: node1Reducer,
    node2: node2Reducer,
    ...
});
```